# Query multivalued field in solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I have a document like this:
    `<doc>

    <arr name="StartDate">

      <date>2012-08-18T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-06-28T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2013-02-28T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-04-16T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-08-06T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-05-18T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-07-04T17:00:00Z</date>

    </arr>

    <arr name="EndDate">

      <date>2012-09-29T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-06-29T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2013-04-16T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-05-07T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-08-15T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-06-22T17:00:00Z</date>

      <date>2012-08-01T17:00:00Z</date>

    </arr>

    </doc>`

I have date range and want to find a pair of StartDate and EndDate that cover the range. For example the first pair of startDate and EndDate (2012-08-18 TO 2012-09-29) returns true if the input range (x, y) is 2012-08-18 < x and 2012-09-29 > y.

I wrote a query like this:
**StartDate:[1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z TO 2012-08-18T00:00:00.000Z] AND EndDate:[2012-09-29T00:00:00.000Z TO 2099-01-01T00:00:00.000Z]**
 but the problem is SOLR search ALL match dates in the set of 14 items above, while I just want to compare them one by one (1 with 1, 2 with 2...).

Please help tell me how to do that. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar model, but there is not, to my knowledge, any way to do this in Solr.

Solr has a "flat" index, which means that if your base entity looks like this:

```
dates: [
  (start1, end1),
  (start2, end2),
  (start3, end3)
]
```

it will be flattened to:

```
start_date: [ start1, start2, start3 ]
end_date: [ end1, end2, end3 ]
```

And since there is no connection between each `start` and `end` pair, so there's no way to do a range query on them. For this to work directly in Solr, you'd probably have to implement a custom Solr field type which maintained this connection.

Another solution is to have a separate [Solr core](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) with the date fields and the `id` of your primary entity. The downside of this is that you can't combine the date search with filtering on other fields of the primary entity.

Comment: For your first solution. I'm thinking about using Solr 'function' query. As long as we can iterate through the 2 arrays, we can find the way to do it. Just my thought. I'm very new to Solr. Thanks, waiting for other answers.

Comment: I doubt ordering is guaranteed for the multi-value fields; I haven't read the source to check this, but it's certainly possible you'll end up with `[start2, start1, start3]` instead.

Comment: Other way I can see is to denormalize (start1, end1) into one value that you can search on. However this might not be that easy/possible at all

Comment: Fuxi. I think of you answer. Maybe we can merge StartDate and EndDate to, says StartEndDate <string>2012-08-18T17:00:00Z,2012-09-29T17:00:00Z</string> and write a query like this: StartEndDate:[1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z TO GetStartDate()] AND StartEndDate:GetEndDate() TO 2099-01-01T00:00:00.000Z]. Will it work? Can you help to point out how to write a function if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious - what was the final solution here? Did an aggregated field work? And how do you use that for filtering? I have the same problem and I would like to narrow down the available options.

Comment: @cdonner One way to do this in Solr 4 is with dynamic fields; you can specify pairs with names like `start_1_date` and `end_1_date` then query over the each of the possible fields. In the newly released Solr 5, there's a [DateRangeField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates), but I've not tried this yet.

Comment: Thanks - I am working with Drupal's search api and don't have the full set of query syntax and features available. I worked around the issue by doing a separate SQL query before the search that find the date matches and by adding a filter to only include those nodes in the solar search.